# Is it possible to have a multi-modal network in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, multimodal-network, austria

I would like to design a multimodal network in QGIS and connect it with real-time traffic data (for road, rail and inland waterway). Is it possible to have a multimodal network in QGIS? And how can I get the real-time traffic data in Austria?

I already have a multimodal network in ArcGIS and I know that there is DTF files from NAVTEQ for roads. Is there any similar file formats for rail and inland waterway?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  It looks like you are asking three questions which makes it hard to do clean Q&A which is the aim of this site.  I recommend that you focus on asking the question which is most important to you first.

Comment: I prioritize the questions like this:
1- Is it possible to have a multi-modal network in QGIS? 
2- How can I get the real-time traffic data in Austria?

Comment: That definitely looks like it should be two questions rather than being lumped into one.